# Will TFS Rollback also revert the check-in date?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

With VS 2019, I checked in some changes that I made to a dtsx package. The changeset history looks like below; my changeset is `4021`:

```
Changeset    Change    User        Date    Path
4021         Edit      Joe Smith   2/8/23  $/dev/ReadFile.dtsx
3816         Edit      Harry Joe   9/2/22  $/dev/ReadFile.dtsx
```

I want to rollback to changeset 3816, but I also want to remove changeset `4021` from the History.

Is this possible? I understand that the *rollback* will revert `ReadFile.dtsx` to the changeset that I selected, but it seems that I have to check-in again, which will add another changeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot delete a changeset from history*. The rollback command will reverse the change as a new checkin and History will be preserved.

'*' you might be able to if you go poking around in the TFS database, but this is dangerous and should not be attempted.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only way another user would know that it's actually a rollback (and not an actual change) would be to add those details in the Comments section on check-in?

Comment: The checkin type will be "rollback" so it should be obvious

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know somewhere in the logs it specified that it was a "rollback".